# Immediately update cookies in KOA

Tags: node.js, koa

When using `ctx.cookies.set()`, KOA adds a 'set-cookie' header to the response. However, `ctx.cookies.get()` retains the cookie (if any) from the original request. This seems counter-intuitive if I'm overwriting it. Is there not a way to have the getter reflect the new value immediately, in the same request?

```
h = uuidv4();
console.log('set new cookie',h);
ctx.cookies.set('uuid',h,{httpOnly:false,overwrite:true});

//This outputs undefined or the value that came with the request, 
//not the newly assigned value:
console.log('cookie is',ctx.cookies.get('uuid'));
```

I'm fairly new to node.js. What I'm looking for is something like PHP's  `$_SESSION[]`, in which values are updated and available immediately as well as being written to the response cookie. I understand I could pile the new uuid into `ctx.state`, but it seems cleaner to just be able to access `ctx.cookies.get()` anywhere further down the middleware chain and have access to what I just set it to.

Having a `set()` that doesn't change the result of its `get()` seems like code smell to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: `$_COOKIE` works the same way in PHP. Why not find a koa session middleware if you're just trying to replicate `$_SESSION` in koa?

Comment: Fair point, I just thought it should be possible to do with the standard cookies module.